# Why would my SQL Azure database usage pulsate?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I use the following query to compute database usage in SQL Azure

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, SUM(reserved_page_count) * 8 / 1024) FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
```

which gives exactly the same result as SQL Azure management portal summary pie chart.

The problem is on some days it shows something like 55% space occupied and on some days it shows something like 32% space occupied although the actual database contents only experience minor changes - nothing like massive deletions.

I tried to look at this query results

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
```

but it only yields a ton of magic numbers that don't really help.

Why would database usage have such serious variations?

Answer (score 0):

It probably changes as your primary copy changes roles with one of the secondary copies, or as you are being migrated from a host to another. Is all transparent to you.